# Loop audio and video separately AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, stream, flv

I have this function witch is looping everything in it after the streamed video finishes Is there a way to loop only the streamed video and `shaker(null)` without the audio ? Because the audio is loping to but it length is biger. So basically I need the video and audio to be independently looped.

```
    function NCListener(e:NetStatusEvent){

    if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {

        ns.play("http://media.easyads.bg/ads/display_ads_richmedia/video/avon/maria_ilieva/video_2.flv");
        soundChannel = sound.play(0, 9999);
        shaker(null);
        }
    };


var sound:Sound = new Sound();
var soundChannel:SoundChannel= new SoundChannel();
sound.load(new URLRequest("sound.mp3"));
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoadComplete  );

function onSoundLoadComplete(e:Event):void{
    sound.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoadComplete);

    soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundChannelSoundComplete);
}

function onSoundChannelSoundComplete(e:Event):void{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundChannelSoundComplete);
    soundChannel = sound.play(0, 9999);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For independent looping, you'll need to listen to events on both the NetStream (onPlayStatus) and the SoundChannel (soundComplete).  In the event handler, you'd restart just the media that completed.

It looks like your sample code is just listening to the NetStream.

Comment: I'm doing it. But I need when the video is played and the audio to starts. But because the audio is with bigger length I need them both to be independently.

Comment: I'm not sure why you call `sound.play()` in NCListener, then?

Comment: If you have some other ideas I will be happy to see it please.